# Hide featured post from second page

Tags: featured-post

This is my category page code

<--Featured Post start-->

```
<?php 
$count = 1;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if($count == 1) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<--Featured Post start-->
<?php else : ?>
```

<--Rest of Posts -->

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

---

```
<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) wp_pagenavi(); else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

i dont want featured post to be display after first page, how to prevent ?

Comment: how are you deciding on the "featured post?" are you grabbing the first post or is there a tag/cat you are looking for? Your code above is a bit confusing.

Comment: please have a look here http://pastebin.com/Xp8kcj6v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($count == 1 && !is_paged() ) :
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged

Comment: please explain how to use with this code ? <?php 
$count = 1;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if($count == 1) : ?>

Comment: the code is supposed to replace this section: `if($count == 1) : `